# How to Use Color Saved inside Database to be the background color of the label?

Tags: c#, css, gridview, label

I'm using a label inside a gridview template field i want to set the background color of the label to the one i am geeting from the database which i saved using a colorpicker...is it possible if yes then how...here`s my label control

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<% # Bind("doctorname") %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

I tried this but it didnt work....

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" BackColor='<% # Bind("color") %>' Text='<% # Bind("doctorname") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

BackColor is a control property, not text. You could create a css class on the page, like:

```
.custom-color
{
   background-color: '<% # Bind("color") %>'
}
```

And then you can specify the css class on the control:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="custom-color" Text='<% # Bind("doctorname") %>'></asp:Label>
```